# How to transfer list from Python to Julia?

Tags: python, julia

In Python I created a 3d list of data which I want to have access to in Julia. I wonder how to do that conveniently. If doing by writing in text file, how to parse it from julia? Or maybe there are specialized solutions for that, such as `feather` for dataframes?

For example, in python:

```py
a = [[[0, 1]], [[1, 0.5], [2, 0.5]]]
save_to_convenient_for_parsing_file(a, filename)
```

in julia:

```
a = read_from_convenient_for_parsing_file(filename)
a
>2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}:
 [[0.0, 1.0]]
 [[1.0, 0.5], [2.0, 0.5]]
```

In that example, how `save_to_convenient_for_parsing_file` and `read_from_convenient_for_parsing_file` should look?

Comment: Maybe write to a csv file or some other file format and load it back in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most natural ways to store objects in Python is pickle and it is supported in Julia:

```
import pickle
with open("a.pkl","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(a,f)
```

And now you can do:

```
julia> using Pickle

julia> Pickle.load("a.pkl")
2-element Vector{Any}:
 Any[Any[0, 1]]
 Any[Any[1, 0.5], Any[2, 0.5]]
```

Note that an equivalent of Python's list is a Julia's vector of `Any` values as lists in Python are not typed.

A more universal format would be BSON:

```
import bson
with open("a.bson","wb") as f:
   f.write(bson.dumps({"a":a}))
```

```
julia> using BSON

julia> BSON.load("a.bson")
Dict{Symbol, Any} with 1 entry:
  :a => Any[Any[Any[0, 1]], Any[Any[1, 0.5], Any[2, 0.5]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! However I faced the following issue: my actual list was constructed from `numpy array` by list comprehension. Because of that I've got messy reading from julia, something like this `Any[Any[Defer(:reduce, Defer(:numpy.core.multiarray.scalar), Defer(:build, Defer(:reduce, Defer(:numpy.dtype)`. So I explicitly cast values to float and it worked like should have. Example: before: `list_for_saving = [a for a in some_np_array]` -> messy pickle file. After `list_for_saving = [float(a) for a in some_np_array]` -> worked as in the answer above.

Comment: in your example you had a list of lists - without numpy.
However I believe that pickle and BSON both work with numpy datastructures too.